# How to run echo with command?

Tags: bash, echo

the bash file is

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "
**************************************************
**************************************************
Welcome ${USER}

"Today is $(date)"

Your IP wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -

**************************************************
**************************************************"
```

How to run `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -` in the echo message?

Comment: `echo "Your IP is  $(wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same like you used it for `date`. Anyway you have some weird quotes inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "
**************************************************
**************************************************
Welcome ${USER}

Today is $(date)

Your IP $(wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -)

**************************************************
**************************************************"
```